# Juggling async - learnyounode - code passed and then failed

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

- node version: v4.4.3
- npm version: 3.8.9

#### Error output

```
 Your submission results compared to the expected:
────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
1.  ACTUAL:    "undefined"
1.  EXPECTED:  "Get a dog up ya smokes with as cross as a muster. She'll be right bushranger heaps shazza got us some struth. It'll be fair dinkum flamin he's got a massive rock up. "

2. ACTUAL:    "undefined"
3. EXPECTED:  "Mad as a bonza bloody as stands out like garbo. She'll be right roo my he's got a massive sickie. Lets get some banana bender and come a brekkie. "
4. ACTUAL:    "Built like a tucker-bag when as cross as a two pot screamer. As cross as a bush oyster also mad as a mozzie. "
5. EXPECTED:  "Built like a tucker-bag when as cross as a two pot screamer. As cross as a bush oyster also mad as a mozzie. "
6. ACTUAL:    "undefined"
7. EXPECTED:  ""
8. ACTUAL:    "Built like a tucker-bag when as cross as a two pot screamer. As cross as a bush oyster also mad as a mozzie. "
9. EXPECTED:
10. ACTUAL:    "Get a dog up ya smokes with as cross as a muster. She'll be right bushranger heaps shazza got us some struth. It'll be fair dinkum flamin he's got a massive rock up. "
11. EXPECTED:
12. ACTUAL:    "Mad as a bonza bloody as stands out like garbo. She'll be right roo my he's got a massive sickie. Lets get some banana bender and come a brekkie. "
13. EXPECTED:
14. ACTUAL:    "Built like a tucker-bag when as cross as a two pot screamer. As cross as a bush oyster also mad as a mozzie. "
15. EXPECTED:
16. ACTUAL:    ""
17. EXPECTED:

```

#### My Code

```

```
var http= require ('http');
var final=[];


function cases(index){
var result='';

http.get(process.argv[2+index],function(chunky){
    chunky.setEncoding('utf8')
    chunky.on('data',function(data){

        result+=data;
    });
    chunky.on('error',function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
    chunky.on('end',function(){
        //console.log("this is the result: ",result);

        final[index]=result;
        //console.log("final length is : ",final.length);
       if(final.length===3){
           printResult();
       }

    });
});
}

for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
cases(i);
}

function printResult(){
for (var j=0;j<final.length;j++){
console.log(final[j]);
}

}
```

```
This code actually passed and I could have gone on to the next exercise, but I felt like I should try once again and see what happens.
And then I got a : failed message which I pasted above.

So, what exactly am I doing wrong??
How did this pass and then.... how does it fail now??

EDIT: I read another related thread which said that if we get the 3rd response first then final[2]= whatever response and the length of the array will be three, even if the other 2 responses are not there.
This made sense and so I tried using var count=0 at first and then count++ for each response but even then, the code doesnt work as expected.

Dont know why!!

EDIT: PROBLEM SOLVED --- 
I solved it now. I was using count++ when  I was adding it to response. Instead I incremented count when I was adding it to the final array instead and it worked.

Here's the final code that works now

```
var http= require ('http');
var final=[];
var count=0;


function cases(index){
var result='';

http.get(process.argv[2+index],function(chunky){
    chunky.setEncoding('utf8')
    chunky.on('data',function(data){

        result+=data;

    });
    chunky.on('error',function(error){
        console.log(error);
    });
    chunky.on('end',function(){
        //console.log("this is the result: ",result);
        count++;
        final[index]=result;
        //console.log("final length is : ",final.length);
       if(count===3){
           printResult();
       }

    });
});
}

for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
cases(i);
}

function printResult(){
for (var j=0;j<3;j++){
console.log(final[j]);
}

}
```

Comment: The explanation is correct. Please show us the code with your approach to use `count`.

Comment: I solved it now. I was using count++ when  I was adding it to response. Instead I incremented count when I was adding it to the final array instead and it worked.

Comment: Please [post that as an answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), not an edit to your question :-)

Answer (score 0):

PROBLEM SOLVED --- I solved it now. I was using count++ when I was adding it to response. Instead I incremented count when I was adding it to the final array instead and it worked.

Here's the final code that works now

```
var http= require ('http');
var final=[];
var count=0;


function cases(index){
var result='';

http.get(process.argv[2+index],function(chunky){
chunky.setEncoding('utf8')
chunky.on('data',function(data){

    result+=data;

});
chunky.on('error',function(error){
    console.log(error);
});
chunky.on('end',function(){
    //console.log("this is the result: ",result);
    count++;
    final[index]=result;
    //console.log("final length is : ",final.length);
   if(count===3){
       printResult();
   }

});
});
}

for(var i=0;i<3;i++){
cases(i);
}

function printResult(){
for (var j=0;j<3;j++){
console.log(final[j]);
}

}
```